# Difference between "physical quantities" and "units"?

Tags: units

My textbook, *Atkins' Physical Chemistry*, 11th edition, by Atkins, de Paula, and Keeler, says the following:

> Although it is good practice to use only SI units, there will be occasions where accepted practice is so deeply rooted that physical quantities are expressed using other, non-SI units. By international convention, all physical quantities are represented by oblique (sloping) letters (for instance, $m$ for mass); units are given in roman (upright) letters (for instance m for metre).

I'm confused about what the difference here is between "physical quantities" and "units"?

I would appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: I think that passage explains it pretty well, but to give another example energy is a physical quantity that can be expressed using different units like Joules and calories. Physical quantities describe some property of an object, units are used to express a particular amount of that property.

Comment: @Tyberius So how does the different uses of $m$ and m in the textbook excerpt relate to this?

Comment: That's basically just telling you how to read expressions they write in the book. If you see $F=ma$, you know that m is referring to mass. If you see $1600$ m, it's talking about that many meters, not that number times mass.

Comment: @Tyberius Oh, so *that's* what they were referring to. It wasn't even clear to me until you used the $F = ma$ example. I think this could have been expressed more clearly; they managed to make such a simple point into something much vaguer than reasonable. Anyway, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mass is a physical quantity. Its unit may be gram or kilogram.
Volume is a physical quantity. Its unit may be the liter or the cubic meter

Comment: Yes, it wasn't clear to me what they meant until Tyberius clarified it with his example in the comments.